# Array from static method returns empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't understand what the {length} part is doing. Typeof '{length}' returns 'object' but in the Array.from call it seems to be doing something I don't understand

```
/// this gets array with 0 filled values
const length = 3;
const init2   = 0;
const result2 = Array.from( {length} , () => init2);

console.log(result2); 
>>> Array(3) [ 0, 0, 0 ]
```

But this gets an empty array - changed length to l. Used a new tab in firefox (seems to be same in chrome). I wonder if this is a bug in the javascript engine or my brain.

```
const l = 3;
const init2   = 0;
const result2 = Array.from( {l} , () => init2);

console.log(result2); 
Array []
```

//code based on https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-array-from-applications/

Answer (score 3):

```
{ length }
```

is an object literal. It uses the [shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) syntax. It's similar to doing

```js
{ length: length }
```

So, in the first case, it creates `{ length: 3 }`

Now, [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) expects

- An array-like objects with a [`Symbol.Iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) property (a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), `string` etc)
- OR an object with `length` property and creates an array from it.

`{ l }` syntax creates the object `{ l: 3 }`. This object has neither. So, it doesn't work

Here's a snippet:

```js
const set = new Set([1, 2, 2]),
      string = 'abc',
      array = ['value 1', 'value 2'],
      
      objectWithLength = {
       length: 5
      },
      
      objectWithIterator = {
        [Symbol.iterator]: function*() {
          yield 'iterator 1'
          yield 'iterator 2'
        }
      },
      
      genericObject = {
        someProperty: 10
      }

// call Array.from() on every item
console.log(
  [set, string, array, objectWithLength, objectWithIterator, genericObject]
    .map(v => Array.from(v))
)
```

Comment: If I change the object in the array.from to {"3":3} then I get an empty array const length = 3;
const init2   = 0;
const result2 = Array.from( {"3":3} , () => init2);

console.log(result2); 
Array []

Comment: @JoePythonKing because the object doesn't have the `length` property. It has a property called `"3"`

Comment: Omg , I thought all objects had a length property but the object properties(or rather the key) in the object needs to be called "length" in this array.from()?

Comment: @JoePythonKing Correct. Only arrays and strings have a built-in length property. I've added an example for all the scenarios.

Comment: I think I am getting confused between a property and a key.

Comment: @JoePythonKing property, attribute, key are all used interchangeably. Usually key refers to the name of the property while property refers to the entire key-value pair.

Comment: In the question already answered I think this helps me - ' When Array.from gets a value of property length (5 in this case), then it creates a real array with length 5'. I think in general 'the length property' is an ambiguous reference. They mean the string key/property in the keys iterator.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.from()` uses the length property of the provided object to construct a "new" array from it (as long as the object is not iterable). If you rename `length` with `l` this doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) can be an array-like object. An array-like object is an object with `length` property. So `{length}` is a contracted form of `{length: length}` object and it is accepted. While `{l}` is a contracted form of `{l: l}` object with `length` property undefined, so it produces an empty array,